# i need help converting this program into a while loop from for loop with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, while-loop

convert this for loop into a while loop finding pi

```
import turtle
import math
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-400,-400,400,400)

t.pu()
t.speed(0)
t.goto(0,-400)
t.pd()
t.color("green")
t.circle(400)
t.color("red")
hits=0.0
numdarts = 100
for i in range(numdarts):
    randx = random.uniform(-1,1)
    randy = random.uniform(-1,1)
    if (randx**2+ randy**2)<1:
        hits+=1.0

    t.pu()
    t.goto(400*randx,400*randy)
    t.pd()
    t.dot()
print 4*(hits/numdarts)
wn.exitonclick()
```

want to use a while loop instead to estimate the value of pi, given the acceptable amount of error for the approximation

Comment: What prevents you from doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if numdarts is bisher than 0 and countdown numdarts.
Like this:

```
numdarts =100
while numdarts > 0:
     numdarts-=1
     [rest of Loop]
```

Though I don't see, why you should do this in this special usecase, because you might run into an endless Loop.

Answer (score 0):

to convert this `for` loop to a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while True:
    #your code
    i += 1
    if i == numdarts:
        break
```

this basically keep looping from 0 to 99 same as the range (100)